# What are some inexpensive easy to use SPI devices I can experiment with?

Tags: spi, raspberry-pi, gpio

**Introduction**

I'm completely new to EE, but have decades of software development experience. I want to learn to interface with multiple SPI devices on a single SPI interface on a Raspberry Pi. I'd like to start cheap and easy. I only know about complex and/or expensive devices like LCDs and radio interfaces.

**Question**

I'd like to compile a list of device options (they don't have to be specific device models or where to buy them) that a budget constrained kid looking to escape a coal mining town in Appalachia could start with. (Even though that is not my situation now, it was a few decades ago and that is always who I think of.)

**Specifics**

My ultimate goal is to read multiple MAX31855 chips. Before I go investing in 4 of these $8 chips and 4 $26 thermocouples, I'd like to try connecting a few cheap (<$1?) SPI devices so I can work on the python code to interface with SPI.

If I totally fail at this, I'd rather only be out a few dollars.

What so you recommend?

Comment: It's not that this is a bad question, but simply that it was decided a long time ago not to allow part shopping questions and to avoid questions which solicit a broad variety of answers.

Comment: @Chris: But this is not really a shopping question.

Comment: Why not just buy the parts? It doesn't get any easier than SPI.

Comment: Geeh everyone, thanks for the cold welcome. This was my first stop before doing anything in EE. This community makes me think I ought to stick with software development. @MattYoung, while SPI is easy, the part I'm talking about starting with is a thermocouple reading chip. That seems overwhelmingly complicated to me. Every contact/solder point introduces variables in the reading. I'd rather start with a better chance of success.

Comment: @Leon, Peter, and the others: the OP asks for a part(s) recommendation for a specific purpose with a specific (<$1?, note the ?) constraint. He *does* describe his situation and what he is trying to solve (cheap part (throwaway level) to gain experience with SPI). He does not ask where to buy it. In my book this is not a shopping question.

Comment: Richard, while I'd agree that the response you have gotten here has been unnecessarily and uselessly negative, "what are some" type questions are generally not a fit for the stack exchange sites, because they tend not to have answers which are definitive enough for this model.

Comment: I think this would seem like a reasonable question if it were slightly reworded; the goal isn't just to get cheap parts, but also to have something that's easy to understand and work with.  I think a 74HCT595 or equivalent and 74HCT165 would make an excellent pair of parts not just because they're dirt-cheap, but because it's really easy to see what's going on with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

74HC595 : 8 bit serial-in parallel-out shift register with holding register; this might not sound like SPI to you but it definitely is.

MCP23S17 : a bit above $1, but a really versatile 16-bin I/O extender. (MCP23017 is essentially the same chip but with an I2C interface).

RFM73 or NRF24L01 : more like $3, but nice little short-distance radio modules.

Comment: I have chosen this as the answer for now because an "SPI capable shift register" regardless of the model is an excellent choice for learning SPI. It can be used to read from DIP switches or write to LEDs. I'm still interested in other suggestions though. Keep them coming!

Comment: Note that the 595 can be used form output only, but you can go to a TTL selection guide and find you an input shift register.